# How to delete lines from file with sed\awk?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, freebsd

I have file, with lines, contains ip with netmask
a.b.c.d/24
w.x.y.z/32
etc
How to delete delete specific row? 
i'm using

```
sed -ie "s#a.b.c.d/24##g" %filname%
```

but after the removal is an empty string in file.

It should run inside a script, with ip as parameter and also work in freebsd under sh.

Answer (score 15):

#### Sed solution

```
 sed -i '/<pattern-to-match-with-proper-escape>/d' data.txt
```

`-i` option will change the original file.

#### Awk solution

```
awk '!/<pattern-to-match-with-proper-escape>/' data.txt
```

Comment: this will not work if we have a network mask separated by '/'

Comment: @evilmind - sure it will, he'll just have to escape the slash that denotes the netmask.  Oh, except for the typo in the awk solution.

Comment: `-i` does not change the original file.  It creates a new file and overwrites the original file, breaking hard links along the way.

Answer (score 6):

Using sed:

```
sed -i '\|a.b.c.d/24|d' file
```

**Command line arg:**
For the input being command line argument, say 1st argument($1):

```
sed -i "\|$1|d" file
```

Replace $1 with appropriate argument number as is your case.

Answer (score 2):

You should use d (delete) not g. Also do not use s (replacement).

```
sed -ie '/a.b.c.d\/24/d' %filename%
```

In a script you should using it in this way

```
IP=$1
IPA=${IP////\\/}
sed -i /"${IPA}"/d %filename%
```

And the script parameter should be called in this way:

```
./script.sh a.b.c.d/24
```

Comment: i'm using a bash file where ip/subnet is an argument in comamnd line, what to do in this case?

Comment: Look at the answer now ... :)

Comment: the script for the clients and it would be difficult to explain that they need to escape some characters =\

Comment: thx, work perfect on bash, but how to run it  with sh in freebsd?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any freebsd here.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i -lne 'print unless(/a.b.c.d\/24/)' your_file
```

or in awk if you donot want to do inplace editing:

```
 awk '$0!~/a.b.c.d\/24/' your_file
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape the dots in your regex, and add word boundaries.  `23` is not the same as `123`.

Comment: Ruby version of the above Perl: `ruby -i -lne 'print $_ unless $_ =~ /a.b.c.d\/24/' your_file`